# How to add remote Glassfish OpenSource 3.1.2 in Eclipse Indigo?

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

Just like in the title; I have a remote server and I want to access it from inside Eclipse.

[image: Remote Server]

[image: Setup]

Why do I have to set the local directory for the server? Somebody please tell me how to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set a directory because the server is supposed to be local. You could have a mount(or mapping in windows) on a remote server but the process of the JVM running Glassfish would run locally again.

If you just want to debug:

Enable debugging in the administration console of Glassfish and restart the domain.

Attach to the Glassfish debug port with Eclipse | Debug Configurations... | Remote Java Application.